# Show/Hide route components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React application which has routes like so:

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/edituser/:username" component={EditUser}/>
        <Route path="/createuser/:type" component={EditUser}/>
        <Route path="/listusers" component={ListUsers}/> 
</Switch>
```

ListUsers component shows a table with pagination where each component in the table has a link which points to `/edituser/:username`.

I can edit users by clicking on the item in the table but as expected with react, once I go back to `listusers/` the component is loaded again and I will be on the first page of users. I want to be on the page from where I accessed the user in the first place.

What is the best pattern to achieve this? I thought about passing in the page number to `/edituser` and then back to `/listuser` but then again I have to load all the paginated results again. Is local storage the only option? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the page number to the URL in the `/listusers` endpoint. Maybe something like `/listusers/2` or `/listusers?page=2` this way, when you hit the browser's back button, you're directly there. One last thing you could do but I wouldn't advise in this case is to store the page number in the history state.

As a rule of thumb, in order to get back, prefer using the history than using local storage.

If you really want to keep the data in memory, you can always use a store that is in a higher component (the root component for example) and keep the previous query over there. However you'll need to be careful about a lot of routing issues in such cases:

- cache invalidation: the data changed on the server side in the mean time
- user somehow gets back to a page with another table page number
- loaded user presses the browser `back` button

Comment: I am aware I can do this as I mentioned but my issue is that when you pass the page number like so, I still have to load all the data back in to the table as the data comes from a database. When the routes are switched,the component is unmounted and the state is lost. I think redux might be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your problem:

1) Pass last active page ad route parameter and set your pagination accordingly.

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/edituser/:username" component={EditUser}/>
        <Route path="/createuser/:type" component={EditUser}/>
        <Route path="/listusers/:pageNumber" component={ListUsers}/> 
</Switch>
```

on your `componentDidMount` you can use it to set state. For example :

`const pageNumber = this.props.match.params.pageNumber;`

2) Pass `state` prop in your routing. For example :

```
<Link 
    to={{ 
    pathname: '/listusers', 
    state: { pageNumber: 1 } 
  }}/>
```

on your `componentDidMount` you can use it to set state. For example :

`const pageNumber = this.props.location.state.pageNumber;`

Comment: I am aware I can do this as I mentioned but my issue is that when you pass the page number like so, I still have to load all the data back in to the table as the data comes from a database. When the routes are switched,the component is unmounted and the state is lost. I think redux might be the solution?

Comment: Yes you got it right in such case go for redux. If its single page application then you can also load data in main component and pass it as `props` in child.